# Outdated "Suggest and vote on tag synonyms" privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, privileges

On the [Suggest and vote on tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privileges page there is the following description:

> #### How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?
>
> When viewing a tag, look for the box at the top of
> the page which contains links to information about the
> tag, or click the `about »` link on the sidebar next to the tag.
>
> ```
> about the foo tag | faq | top users | hot answers | new answers | synonyms
> ```
>
> Click the synonyms link to get started.

It's confusing since the page behind the `about »` link (for example, on the [about page of the java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)) does not contain anything which let users to propose tag synonyms.

Furthermore, the current heads are not the same as in the description. For example, the followings is on the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag page:

```
learn more… | improve tag wiki | top users | synonyms (5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone ahead and updated the [meta privileges wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) for it, which will get updated across the network whenever the devs push the changes out.

Comment: When will it happen? :)

Comment: You can always go bug Shog in the Tavern. They don't do this very often.